# Por que esto no estaria funcionando

Tags: python, array, lista

```py
def rellenar_alt(tablero):
  rTab = tablero.copy()
  alfabeto = list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)))
  for elemento in rTab: 
    for item in elemento:
      item = choice(alfabeto)
  return rTab
```

rTab es una lista cuadrada donde cada elemento es una lista, con n elementos adentro.
No tengo idea de porque no estaría reemplazando los elementos de rTab
Se que podría usar indices y rango para reemplazarlo al estilo

```
rTab[x][y] = choice(alfabeto)
```

pero me preguntaba porque no funcionaria el primer ej.
PD: Si, importe la función choice de random

Desde ya, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues, Python no permite cambiar una lista de esta manera. En el código `item` simplemente es una variable con el contenido del elemento, y cambiando `item` solo tiene efecto sobre si mismo, no sobre `rTab`.

La manera 'Pythonica' para hacer estas cosas, es crear una lista nueva con [*list comprehension*](https://j2logo.com/list-comprehensions-en-python/):

```py
from random import choice

def rellenar_alt(tablero):
    alfabeto = list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)))
    return [[choice(alfabeto) for item in elemento] for elemento in tablero]

tablero = [[0 for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]
rTab = rellenar_alt(tablero)
print(rTab)
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto está relacionado íntimamente con lo que es verdaderamente una variable en Python, no es más que un nombre asociado en todo momento a una referencia a un objeto en memoria. Ni mas ni menos, una variable tampoco tiene tipo, el tipo (clase) es propio del objeto, no de la variable.

Cuando en un ciclo `for in` se recorre una iterable, en cada iteración se obtiene una nueva referencia a un item del mismo, resultado de llamar al método `__next__` del iterador. Dicha referencia se asocia a la variable del ciclo, de forma que podemos referenciar el objeto usando dicha variable.

Es decir `for elemento in rTab:` en cada iteración asocia elemento con una referencia a uno de los objetos `list` contenidos en `rTab`. Esto permite que en el siguiente `for` podamos usar `elemento` para acceder a la sublista.

En `for item in elemento` se itera sobre la sublista y se asocia igualmente una referencia al elemento contenido en la sublista a `item` en cada iteración, de forma que podemos usar dicha variable para acceder al objeto.

En `item = choice(alfabeto)` **reasignamos a la variable** `item` un nuevo objeto, por lo que esta pasa a quedar asociada a una referencia al objeto retornado por `choice` y deja de estarlo al item de la lista referenciada por `elemento` que pierde una referencia, pero dejando totalmente intacto éste.